# goodness of fit / likelihood of data given model for loess

Tags: time-series, maximum-likelihood, goodness-of-fit, likelihood-ratio, loess

## Question

How can I compute the likelihood of a set of data points given a LOESS fit (of the same and/or other data points)?

## Alternative

Are there other (better?) ways to assess how 'good' a LOESS fit is and ultimately how much better it fits the given set of data compared to a LOESS fit based on another set of data?

---

## Background

To put the question in perspective and enable further suggestions, this is the kind of problem I am trying to solve leading to this question:

### Definition

Assume time series data of a process with very complex behaviour described by the (unknown) function $f(t)$.
Further assume several ($n$) replicates of measurements $f_i^j$ (with $i\in\{ 1..n\}$ corresponding to the replicate and $j\in\{1..n_i\}$ enumerating the measurements of replicate $i$).
Finally, assume the replicates might be shifted against each other by a (small enough) time differerence $\Delta t_i\in[\Delta t_\min, \Delta t_\max]$.
Thus, $f_i^j=f(t_0+\Delta t_i^j+\Delta t_i)+\epsilon$, where $\Delta t_i^j\in \Delta T_i$ represents the known (non-uniform) time differences between the begin of measurements $t_0$ and the time measurement $f_i^j$ was taken ($|\Delta T_i|=n_i$) and $\epsilon$ represents (small enough) noise (with unknown distribution).

### Simplification (I)

Define $T_i\ni t_i^j:=t_0+\Delta t_i^j$.

Further, w.l.o.g., let $n=2$ and $t_0=0$.

This makes $T_i=\Delta T_i$ and $f_i^j=f(t_i^j + \Delta t_i+\epsilon)$.

### Objective

Approximate $f(t)$ by $\tilde{f}(t)$ in the interval $[t_0,t_0+\displaystyle\max_{i\in\{1..n\}}\max_{j\in\{1..n_i\}}\Delta t_i^j]=[0,\max\bigcup_i T_i]$ based on the measurements $f_i^j\;\forall j\in\{1..n_i\}\,\forall i\in\{1..n\}$.

### Problem (I)

The sample shifts $\Delta t_i$ are unknown.

### Simplification (II)

W.l.o.g., let $\Delta t_1=0$.

Thus, only $\Delta t_2$ remains to be estimated from the data.

### Solution (I)

For each replicate $i\in n$, $f(t+\Delta t_i)$ can be approximated by a function $\tilde{f_i}(t)$ based on the measurements $f_i^j$ $\forall j\in\{1..n_i\}$ of that replicate using LOESS.

Then, $\Delta t_2$ can be optimized over $[\Delta t_\min,\Delta t_\max]$, such that it minimized the distance $d(\tilde{f_1},\tilde{f_2})$ of the per-replicate fits.

### Problem (II)

How to define the distance function $d$.

### Alternative

Obviously, maximizing a similarity would be possible, too.

### Solution (II) (?)

Calculate the likelyhood ratio $\frac{L(f_1^j|\tilde{f_2})*L(f_2^j|\tilde{f_1})}{L(f_1^j|\tilde{f_1})*L(f_2^j|\tilde{f_2})}$.